# Why is 'le' used as a suffix on 'mantén' in this example?

Tags: traducción, gramática

On SpanishDict this sentence is given as an example of "mantener":

> *Manténle la cabeza al bebé con la mano bajo el cuello.*
>   Support the baby's head with your hand under his neck.

What is the exact purpose of 'le' as a suffix on 'mantén' here? It must be a IO pronoun but what does it refer to?  Is this a case of "dativo posesivo"?
Would "Manténte" give the same translation or would that indicate that the verb is "mantenerse" and have a different meaning? Finally, what would be the negation of this statement?

Comment: The example is misspelled, it should be *mantenle*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *-le* suffix refers to the baby, and is used along with *al* to show that *la cabeza* belongs to the baby. This is a very common way of indicating possession in Spanish, and is the same as saying *mantén la cabeza del bebé*. If you were translating literally, you might say *To the baby, support the head...*.

Another example of this structure is:

> *A él le han robado el coche.*

'They have stolen his car', or more literally: 'to him, they have stolen the car.'

*Mantente la cabeza* on the other hand, would suggest that you are supporting your own head, and would be analogous to *mantén tu cabeza*.

The negation of the statement would be:

> *No le mantengas* la cabeza al bebé con la mano bajo el cuello.

Comment: Note the spelling is *mantente* not *manténte*

Comment: You're right. Duly edited